# Are there any Java libraries than can read hierarchical xmp data from files?

Tags: apache-tika, xmp

I tried looking into Apache Tika, but it seems to flatten XMP keywords to a single level.

Are there any Java libraries than can read hierarchical xmp data from files? Even just image files would suffice, but the more file types the better.